# What is the difference between MK_CONTROL and VK_CONTROL in Win32 API?

Tags: c++, winapi

What is the difference between MK_CONTROL and VK_CONTROL in Win32 API?

Firstly, I checked the defined values.

MK_CONTROL : 0x0008
VK_CONTROL : 0x11

Secondly, I tested in my simple code like this.

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    if(wParam & MK_CONTROL)     // This works here.
        abort();
    if(wParam & VK_CONTROL)     // This doesn't work here.
        abort();    

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if(wParam & MK_CONTROL)     // This doesn't work here.
        abort();
    if(wParam & VK_CONTROL)     // This works here.
        abort();    

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    if(wParam & MK_CONTROL)     // This doens't work here.
        abort();
    if(wParam == VK_CONTROL)    // This doesn't work here.
        abort();
```

Does wParam value depend on the state of mouse device?

What is the difference between MK_.. and VK_.. thing?

Comment: VK_CONTROL is the virtual key number for the Ctrl key.  It is only valid in keyboard messages like WM_KEYDOWN.  MK_CONTROL is only valid in mouse messages, it is flag that indicates that the Ctrl key was down when the message was generated.  It helps you to detect, say, the user holding down the Ctrl key while clicking.  Ctrl+Click is used to expand selections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of `wParam` depends entirely on which message you have been sent. The documentation for each message tells you which values are meaningful for that message.